# Meteorite package install asks for github password

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Some packages that I install with

```
mrt add [package]
```

give me an error after asking for a username / password for github.

I exit, and when I restart, the app crashes.   mrt remove [package] claims to remove the package but doesn't. I physically have to go in and remove the references to smart.lock, smart.json, etc.  Is this a bug, or is this something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is in your smart.json file & which package is this?

Comment: I'm creating different boilerplates for meteor, so I've added about 130 packages through meteorite.   mrt add natural   mrt add wordnet  - those are two off the top of my head

Comment: The package hasn't been published properly. The git repository used was `https://github.com/pent/meteor-wordnet.git` when it should be `https://github.com/Pent/meteor-wordnet.git`. Github urls for repositories are case sensitive. It might be worth telling the author to update it

Comment: A word around is to add it in to your smart.json manually by using `"wordnet": {git:"https://github.com/Pent/meteor-wordnet.git}` to set a custom git repository for the package

Comment: A preventative measure should be put in place to prevent this in future : https://github.com/oortcloud/atmosphere/issues/41 & also put in a patch at https://github.com/Pent/meteor-wordnet/pull/1

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.  You'd think the package publishers would have checked their own work.

Answer (score 0):

Meteorite has been replaced. If you are running Meteor 0.9.0 or higher, you can just run `meteor add mrt:wordnet` to add it your app.